# Have to click two times to do a method in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, meteor, materialize

Hey I'm currently working on a project in Meteor and React and I'm currently styling the front end with Materialize. For the dropdown and side-nav to work I need to add some jquery lines in some methods. 
The problem here is that I need to click at the buttons two times for the dropdown and sidebar to activate or show themselves, but after i've clicked two times for the first time it works with just one click.
These are the methods:

```
showDropdown(){
    $(".dropdown-button").dropdown();
}

collapse(){
    $('.button-collapse').sideNav({ menuWidth: 300, closeOnClick: true });
}
```

constructor:

```
export default class Navigation extends TrackerReact(React.Component) {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.showDropdown= this.showDropdown.bind(this);
    this.collapse = this.collapse.bind(this);
}
```

And this is where I am using these methods in the rendering:

```
render(){
    var navOptions;
    if (Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), 'user')){
        navOptions = (
            <div>
        <nav>
            <div className="nav-wrapper">
                <a href="/" className="brand-logo">SeniorSmart</a>
                <a href="" onClick={this.collapse} data-activates="mobile-demo"  className="button-collapse"><i className="material-icons">menu</i></a>
                <ul id="nav-mobile" className="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                    <li><a href="/">Hjem</a></li>
                    <li><a className='dropdown-button' href='' onClick={this.showDropdown} data-activates='dropdown1'>Drop Me!</a></li>
                    <li><a href="collapsible.html">JavaScript</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
                <ul id="dropdown1" className="dropdown-content">
                    <li><a href="/finn_aktiviteter">Finn aktiviteter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Mine venners aktiviteter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Mine påmeldinger</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/opprett_aktivitet">Opprett aktivitet</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul className="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
                    <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
                    <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
                    <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
                    <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    )
```

Comment: Why Materialize? There are plenty of Material Design React libraries such as http://www.material-ui.com/#/

Answer (score 0):

You have to click twice because those jQuery plugins need to be initialized. Your first click init them, then they just work normally with all other clicks come after.

To avoid this, you should initialize these plugins inside `componentDidMount`, but you have to make sure that the DOM elements to be used are put on the screen.

As I see in your code, the nav is only rendered if the logged-in user has user role. Therefore if user do not have that role, the nav element will not be rendered so as the plugins can not be initialized.